# Programmatically add, remove columns, rows in datagridview which was created programmatically

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

HI their i am trying to create a dynamic text editor which will have tabs and option to add, remove datagridviews using buttons. Also in datagridviews, columns and rows could be added programmatically. I have reached till following code:

```
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim tbpg As TabPage = TabControl1.SelectedTab
        Dim dgview As New DataGridView
        Controls.Add(dgview)
        dgview.Location = New Point(5, 5)
        dgview.Size = New Size(250, 250)
        dgview.ColumnCount = 5
        dgview.RowCount = 5
        tbpg.Controls.Add(dgview)
    End Sub
```

also

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
            Dim clm As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
            clm.DataPropertyName = "Property Name"
            clm.HeaderText = "Header Name"
            clm.Name = "Column Name"
            DataGridView1.Columns.Add(clm)
        ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
            DataGridView1.Rows.Add()
        End If
        End Sub
```

The problem is initially there is no datagridview, so the line `DataGridView1.Columns.Add(clm)` gives error. So i think there should be a `currentdatagridview` or `selecteddatagridview` property.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: Explain What is `DataGridView1` ? have you took any `DataGridView` control on form ? if not then surely it will give you error

Comment: You are adding the DGV to the form, not the TabPage, with   Controls.Add(dgview). You also aren't giving it a name.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the scope of the initial declaration and make it private to your form.

```
Private dgview As DataGridView
```

Then when you create it, refer to the local private

```
dgview = New DataGridView
```

Lastly in your column creation, just keep referring to dgview

```
dgview.Columns.Add()
```

That should cover your requirement.

Full code sample:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private dgView As DataGridView

    Private Sub createDGV()

        dgView = New DataGridView
        TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls.Add(dgView)
        dgView.Location = New Point(5, 5)
        dgView.Size = New Size(250, 250)
        dgView.ColumnCount = 5
        dgView.RowCount = 5

    End Sub

Private Sub addColumn()

    Dim thisDGV As DataGridView = findMyDGV()
    If RadioButton1.Checked = True Then
        Dim clm As DataGridViewTextBoxColumn = New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
        clm.DataPropertyName = "Property Name"
        clm.HeaderText = "Header Name"
        clm.Name = "Column Name"
        thisDGV.Columns.Add(clm)
    ElseIf RadioButton2.Checked = True Then
        thisdgv.Rows.Add()
    End If

End Sub

Private Function findMyDGV() As DataGridView

    For Each ctrl As Control In TabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls
        If TypeOf ctrl Is DataGridView Then
            Return ctrl
        End If
    Next

End Function

    Private Sub TestDGVButton_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles TestButton.Click

        Try
            createDGV()
            addColumn()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("An error occurred: ", ex.Message))
        End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for your response, it would be great if you kindly elaborate.

Comment: Ok, thanks Mort now its working, but as i said earlier that there will be different tabs and  datagridviews will be created on different tabs. Now when i run your code for creating rows and columns, same gets created in the last datagridview created. The rows and columns should be created in the datagridview of tab which is currently selected.